# Dynamically add multiple carousel jquery sliders on a cshtml page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I would like to add multiple jquery sliders on a cshtml page using data from a database. Basically I have a collection of tabs that when active dynamically populate a slider contained within with data from a database.

#### cshtml code with Razor C# hooks:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach(var row in db.Query(queryCategory))
        {
            <li><a href="#@row.Food_Category" data-toggle="tab">@row.Food_Category</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @{bool first = true;}
        @foreach(var row in db.Query(queryCategory))
        {
            var ids= @row.Food_Category;
            <div class="@{if (first){<text>tab-pane active</text> first = false;}else{<text>tab-pane</text>}}" id=@ids>
                <p>I'm in @row.Food_Category.</p>
                <div class="list_carousel">
                <ul id="foo">
                    @foreach(var row1 in db.Query("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Food_Category = @0", ids))
                    {
                        <li>@row1.Food_ID</li>
                    }  
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
                <a id="next2" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
                <div id="pager2" class="pager"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div><!--tabbable-->
```

**The bit I think needs focus:**
The rest of the code is dynamic except this bit. I'm not sure how to go about getting a  unique id for each un-ordered list (e.g foo1, foo2, foo3 dynamically) depending on the number of items in a database column.

```
<ul id="foo">
    @foreach(var row1 in db.Query("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Food_Category = @0", ids))
    {
        <li>@row1.Food_ID</li>
    }  
</ul>
```

**The Jquery bit:**
Here Im not sure, but I think I'll need to set this options true for a range of #id specified dynamically.

```
<script>
//Carousel
    $('#foo').carouFredSel({
        width: '100%',
        scroll: 2,          
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev2',
        next: '#next2',
        pagination: "#pager2",
        mousewheel: true,
        swipe: {onTouch: true}
    });
</script>
```

I'm just starting out with webmatrix & jquery please bear with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the unique ID for each unorder list you can do somethink like this

```
 @int inc=0;
 @foreach(var row in db.Query(queryCategory))
    {
        var ids= @row.Food_Category;
        <div class="@{if (first){<text>tab-pane active</text> first = false;}else{<text>tab-pane</text>}}" id=@ids>
            <p>I'm in @row.Food_Category.</p>
            <div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo@inc++">
                @foreach(var row1 in db.Query("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Food_Category = @0", ids))
                {
                    <li>@row1.Food_ID</li>
                }  
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
            <a id="next2" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
            <div id="pager2" class="pager"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

but if you just want to get carousal dynamically for-each under list you can use for each function in jquery foreach

```
$('ul').each(function(index) {
     $('this').carouFredSel({
        width: '100%',
        scroll: 2,          
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev2',
        next: '#next2',
        pagination: "#pager2",
        mousewheel: true,
        swipe: {onTouch: true}
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get unique id's generated for each ul, however the jquery bit doesn't work, it just ignores them all together. Any ideas?

Comment: have you just tried for one to see if it works without each but by passing the actual id

Comment: Yeah, it does work with the first slider only, but completely ignores the rest. I've even tried the start-with-selector [id^=foo_] still the same story.

Comment: try adding a class to ul and calling it by class

Comment: Really strange behavior, now the attributes are being applied to the class, however they are null or zero for all the slides except the first one.

Comment: ohh do not apply atibute just give it the same class